# Multiple main methods in java package

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have a project in NetBeans where two different classes have public static void main(String[] args) methods. 
When I press F6, the first class' main is always invoked. Why not the second? When I'm trying to display arguments of args, it says that this array is empty.

Comment: What kind of project is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project properties, in the Categories, choose Run.
then there is a Main Class.
Set your main class there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Netbeans, but in Eclipse it automatically sets up a launch config which you can easily customise to specify the full package and class name containing the main class.

Ultimately any program launch is going to effective be a command line execution so I'd expect that netBeans must have a way to customise it as well. You just need to find that and adjust the launch (or setup a new one) for your second program.